# Is it safe to send user id to front end in plain text?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, security, jwt

I have an express app with MongoDB. It creates a user id for each user document. This user id also get encoded in jwt, which creates an illusion for new devs that user id must not be sent to front end in plain text form.

Can someone explain how sending user id to front end can create security issues? As much as i know hackers can't create a jwt with it without my secret string. Neither my express app listens for this user id anywhere in backend. But its critical for frontend as it is being used as seller Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a security risk, it's just *easier to manage* when coding the server. If you're already dealing with login authentication via JWT, and there's no reason for the client-side code to care about the user ID, but the server does need to know it, then you may as well embed everything into the JWT, instead of having *both* the JWT for authentication information *and separately* manage communicating the user ID by some other method.

Comment: why embed everything in JWT? Front end can't access jwt as its httpOnly. User id has to be sent seprately in plain text if we want to access it in front end. i am sending whole user doc when user log in

Comment: *If* you want something to be used by the client, of course don't use JWT. If you're already using JWT for authentication, and there's additional information that it'd be nice for the *server* to have about each device, and the client doesn't need to know it, it'll often be easier to just add onto the existing JWT than to create an entirely different way of communicating.

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying. My server sends user doc to the front end including user id for front end use only. eg: providing a seller link in a product page.

Comment: Like I said, if the front-end needs to use the user ID, then of course don't use JWT, since that just won't work. There's absolutely nothing wrong sending it to the client some other way if the client needs the information - which, in your case, it does.

Comment: but to verify user authentication my server uses only encoded user id. It doesn't listen for plain text user id sent to front end in any request. So i see no security risk in sending user id to front end

Comment: There is no security risk. It's just that embedding the information in the JWT can make the code easier to manage in certain situations. If that doesn't fit *your* situation, that's fine.

Comment: i am new to node/express, what else can be encoded in JWT ?

Comment: You can put into it anything you like, but the general idea is to put into it stuff that helps the server identify information/settings for each individual client, stuff that the client does not need access to. Login credentials are the most common things stored in JWT (including last timestamp to identify when it'll expire), but it can contain anything else in a similar role, something that the server'd frequently need to access, like whether to serve in dark mode, or whether the user is an admin, etc.